# VBA to highlight cells based on current time of day

Tags: excel, vba, gantt-chart

I have a row of cells repeating "1st shift", "2nd shift", and "3rd shift". The top row on the sheet is the dates throughout the year. I already have code to open the file to a specific date (always the day before the current day) and highlight the current day in a blue. I am trying to get the current shift to also highlight the same shade of blue. So if the sheet were being viewed at 7am, the cell with "1st shift" only under the current date would highlight, if viewed at 3pm the cell with "2nd shift" under the current date would highlight, and so on.

Any help is appreciated.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    For I = 1 To 1700
        If Cells(1, I).Value = Date - 1 Then
            ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = I
        End If
    Next
    For I = 1 To 1700
        If Cells(1, I).Value = Date Then
            Cells(1, I).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
            Cells(2, I).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is doable with conditional formatting. What are the hour cutoffs for the shifts?

Answer (score 1):

Since your VBA mentions `1700`, I will assume your shifts start at 1:00, 9:00 and 17:00 respectively.

You can use conditional formatting with the following formulas:

1st shift:

```
=AND(NOW()-TODAY()>1/24,NOW()-TODAY()<9/24)
```

2nd shift:

```
=AND(NOW()-TODAY()>9/24,NOW()-TODAY()<17/24)
```

3rd shift:

```
=OR(NOW()-TODAY()>17/24,NOW()-TODAY()<1/24)
```

Comment: Note that the date in question is "always the day before the current day."

Comment: The problem I am having with using conditional formatting is that all of the correlating shifts cells then highlight, and not just the shift for the current date. The day before reference in VBA is to open the workbook up to the day before the current, so the schedule for the prior day is still visable.